# Simple question about HS algorithm's formul(Optical flow)

Tags: algorithms, optical-flow

In the below pic, I can not understand what `U` vector is? It says `flow field` but I can not imagie what really is the flow field?

[image]

Comment: I think it is derivative of I, dI / dt (frame to frame). And you aim to solve for it

Comment: u is the displacement field which deforms your initial frame. each intensity value at pixel x moved to x+u in the next frame.